# Importing mpp file into SQL Server through ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, ms-project

I have an assignment which is to import mpp file into database via ASP.NET (C#).
Can anyone please advice me on this matter.
Any help is very much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the situation, using Interop isn't necessarily a good choice (have to have Project installed on the machine).

You can use [MPXJ](http://mpxj.sourceforge.net/) to open the mpp file and read the information in it. It's free and open-source and works fairly well, though since it's a port from Java, you have to do some things in a Java way in your .NET code.

A paid option is [ASPOSE.Tasks](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.tasks-for-.net/default.aspx), which is a little nicer to use, but pretty expensive.

Answer (score 0):

Project programmability is [available in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772083.aspx) but docs are [only available for VBA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff920539.aspx).

This should get you going - all the stuff that is available in VBA can be accessed from C# using the Project Primary Interop Assembly from the list [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15s06t57.aspx).

Check out [Application.FileSaveAs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff860768.aspx).